# Calling Azure function from VM using managed identity and REST API

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-vm

Can we make REST API calls to an azure function from an Azure VM? We cannot store user name and password for the API. Is there any other authentication we can use to make a call to the azure function? eg: Managed identity, certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use Managed identity(MSI) to get the token, then use the token to make REST API call to your azure function, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the VM in the portal -> `Identity` -> enable the System-assigned identity.

2.Navigate to the function app in the portal -> `Authentication / Authorization` -> configure your function app with Azure AD auth, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings), don't forget to set the `Log in with Azure Active Directory` , after configuration, it will take a while to create an AD App for your function app, it will appear like below at last.

[image]

3.Then in the function app, create an HTTP trigger to have a test, **Note**: its `Authorization level` needs to be set as `Anonymous`.

[image]

4.In my sample, I RDP into the VM, then use the powershell to get the token, then use the token to call the function, in your case, you can also use other languages depends on your requirements. My function name is `joyfun111`, replace it with yours in the script, it works on my side.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://joyfun111.azurewebsites.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} 
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 
$Token = $content.access_token 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://joyfun111.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?name=world' -Method POST -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $Token"}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If so, you just need to use the function key along with the function url, change the `Authorization level` to `Function`, disable the Azure AD auth in `Authentication / Authorization`, then use the command like below.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://joyfun111.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=10X/IKJIeElrCRIxxxxH6A==&name=world' -Method POST -UseBasicParsing
```

[image]

You can get the function url in the function page.

[image]

Comment: The problem is in the VM we have an application running which can only call an API. The logic to aquire token is not possible from this application. Is there a solution for this scenario?

Comment: Yes, we can use function url, but that key will be openly available in the VM for anyone to acess, right? Is it possible to prevent that?

Comment: @BlueClouds If so, I don‘t think it is possible, anyway you need some auth credentials, it is not possible completed in one call. Even if you use the function key and not want expose it, you need to make another call to get it first.